# Custom location for postgis extension .control file

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-extensions

I am trying to install the `postgis` extension on my database, which resides on a web hosting service. The problem is that the control files seem to have to be found in `/package/host/localhost/postgresq-9.3.2-1`. I am using a hosting company where all we can access is what is in our respective `home/` folders. The Postgres executables are found in the root directories which we cannot access.

I have successfully installed the PostGIS binaries, but now when I try to create the extension with `CREATE EXTENSION postgis`, I get the error `ERROR: could not open extension control file /package/host/localhost/postgresql-9.3.2-1/share/extension/postgis.control`. I cannot write anything to this directory since it is just intended to store the executables for anyone to access via some scripts the hosting provider as set up.

Can I have this .control file be somewhere else instead? Or am I just out of luck entirely?

Comment: Have you tried to ask your hosting company?  They are definitely in the position of being able to help you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be rather a vendor support request.

Comment: Well I just wanted to know if it was possible to use an "off site" control file in the first place

Comment: As it sounds, you (`postgres`, maybe) don't have permissions on the file, so even if there were a way, you would be out of luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not 100% proven, but the following pass of the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createextension.html) suggests you just cannot have your control files in other locations:

> **extension_name**
>
> The name of the extension to be installed. PostgreSQL will create the extension using details from the file `SHAREDIR/extension/extension_name.control`.

I can imagine one can work it around on systems supporting symbolic links - but in your case this does not help as well, as you cannot create the symlink at the right location either.